# Semantic-ui-react Card not showing as a card. How to fix

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

The card component is not appearing as a card. Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Here is the code:

```
import React from "react"
import { Card, Image, Button } from "semantic-ui-react"
 
export default class ProjectCard extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Card>
                <Card.Content header={"Project Title"} textAlign="center" />
                <Card.Content
                    style={{
                        height: "200px",
                        backgroundImage: `url(https://pixabay.com/images/id-1076536/)`,
                        backgroundSize: "cover",
                    }} >
                    <Card.Meta style={{ color: "white" }}>
                        Subtitle
                    </Card.Meta>
                </Card.Content>
                <Card.Content> 
                    <Card.Description>
                        Project Description
                    </Card.Description>
                </Card.Content>
                <Card.Content extra>
                    <Button className="ui button">
                        Code
                    </Button>
                    <Button className="ui button">
                        Demo
                    </Button>
                </Card.Content>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you setup semantic ui using npm or cdn?

Comment: I used npm install

Comment: @Drkwizard Did you make sure to include the minified CSS file to your entry point script? I don't think anything will work without adding `import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'`

Comment: I'll double check that to be sure.